# Generate HTML using Qt

Tags: html, c++, qt, html-generation

I try to programmatically generate HTML using Qt 5.7 and C++.

I would like to avoid using simple text streaming since this does not check HTML syntax.

I tried to use `QTextDocument` and `toHtml()` but it seems not to work very well. It generally supports a small HTML subset only and a lot of standard elements must still be coded into strings manually.

Is there a clean way to generate HTML code using Qt/C++? Maybe some class that does for HTML what `QDomDocument` does for XML?

Comment: As far as I know, XML is a kind of HTML. Why don't you use XML to generate HTML tags?

Comment: No, HTML is not valid XML. XHTML is, but not HTML. E.g. think of <br>.

Comment: I see! Thanks for explaining.

Comment: I would not recommend using the deprecated `QDomDocument`, but you can convert between XHTML and HTML using third party libraries such as TidyLib.

Comment: @MrEricSir: QDomDocument is deprecated?! What is the replacement?

Comment: @Silicomancer See the bottom of this man page: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-module.html

Comment: Stream classes as replacement for QDomDocument... that's horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended creating my own template and DOM bases template classes supporting the HTML subset I need.